# Give existing matplotlib axes object kwargs

Tags: matplotlib

I'd like to give an existing axes object a dictionary of keyword arguments. Is this possible?

ie something like

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kwargs = {'xlim':(0, 2), 'ylabel':'y'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.give_kwargs(**kwargs)
```

I see that the `matplotlib.Axes` class has a `**kwargs` argument, but (I'm pretty sure) that's only available during the initialization of the object, not after the object already exists.

### Edit:

To avoid [the X Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/), Here's the background for wanting to do something like this.

What I find myself doing a lot is creating functions that plot some generalized data and I have to add 5+ extra arguments to handle all of the "set" methods for the axes:

```py
def fancy_plot(data_arg1, dataarg2, xlim=None, ylabel=None):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(data[data_arg1], data[data_arg2])

    if xlim: ax.set_xlim(xlim)
    if ylabel: ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
```

Comment: I am not sure if the creation of the axes jointly with the figure is necessary in your case. Regarding your Edit I believe creating the Figure and Axes separately might be the easier way of doing this. Create `fig = plt.figure()` and then add the axes with `ax = fig.add_subplot(**kwargs)`. This way you can still have the ax, and fig pair for later use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can treat your `kwargs` dictionnary like a dict of methods and arguments.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kwargs = {'set_xlim': (0, 2), 'set_ylabel': 'y'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for (method, arguments) in kwargs.items():
    getattr(ax, method)(*arguments)
```

Alternatively, if all methods follow the `set_something` naming convention:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kwargs = {'xlim': (0, 2), 'ylabel': 'y'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for (method, arguments) in kwargs.items():
    getattr(ax, f"set_{method}")(*arguments)
```

You can then wrap the `getattr` part in a `try-except` in case your dictionnary contains names that are not existing `ax` methods.

```
for (method, arguments) in kwargs.items():
    try:
        getattr(ax, f"set_{method}")(*arguments)
    except AttributeError:
        print("Please everyone panic.")
```

Comment: I have an issue with 
`for method, arguments in kwargs:`//
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)//

i think it should be 
`for method, arguments in kwargs.items():`